# How to update SQL column inside an arithmetic operation?

Tags: mysql

I want to update my `S` quantity of my items from an arithmetic operation result. Can anyone give me correction of my query?

```
SELECT 
    item.S - 2 AS 'AfterMinus' 
FROM
    item 
WHERE 
    item.nama = "Phantom Extent - Iris",

UPDATE item 
SET S = AfterMinus 
WHERE nama = "Phantom Extent - Iris"
```

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html and try again (what you currently have is not valid sql)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an `UPDATE` is different to a `SELECT` here is a set of examples derived from your question

> ```
> CREATE TABLE item(
>    nama VARCHAR(21) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   ,s    INTEGER  NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO item(nama,s) VALUES ('Phantom Extent - Iris',12);
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from item
> ```
>
> ```
> nama                  |  s
> :-------------------- | -:
> Phantom Extent - Iris | 12
> ```

> ```
> update item
> set s = s-2
> where nama = 'Phantom Extent - Iris'
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from item
> ```
>
> ```
> nama                  |  s
> :-------------------- | -:
> Phantom Extent - Iris | 10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ceb5090e81b16602ba34662a463bca07)*